# Is there an efficient algorithm to determine if a linear matrix inequality has a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

Are there any fast algorithms to determine if a linear matrix inequality (LMI) problem $Ax \leq b$ has a solution?

I am aware that linear programming and the simplex algorithm in particular may be used to solve linear optimization problems subject to LMI constraints ($\min(c^Tx) \text{ subject to: } Ax \leq b$) but I am curious if there are fast methods of proving that an LMI is solvable without necessarily finding a solution. For example, some criterion analogous to $\det(A) \neq 0$ for linear equality equations $Ax=b$.

Comment: If the determinant of an $nXn$ matrix is zero, there are no solutions. Otherwise, you can use [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#:~:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20Cramer's%20rule,system%20has%20a%20unique%20solution.&text=Cramer's%20rule%20implemented%20in%20a,than%20two%20or%20three%20equations.) to find those solutions.

Comment: That is certainly true of a matrix equation $Ax=b$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, however for an LMI $Ax \leq b$ where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, there is generally not a single solution and so  Crammer's rule can't be directly applied. If there are solutions to the LMI, then they will fall within some region in $n$ dimensional space.

Comment: Maybe Farkas' Lemma will help you
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not meaningfully. Up until a logarithmic factor the algorithms must be the same speed.

To see why, we can append $c^T$ as a row to $A$, and $q$ to $b$. Then by solving whether $Ax \leq b$ you find whether $q$ is an achievable value for the minimization problem. Then you can try various $q$ in a binary search manner to approach the minimal value quickly.

---

This holds quite generally, usually. In a lot of cases in computer science the 'decision problem' (does a solution exist) is roughly as hard as the 'optimization problem' (find the optimal solution) because very often you can simply binary search for the optimal solution given a decider. This is also neat for computational complexity results however, since decision problems are easier to study but allow you to put bounds on the optimization problems we are often interested in.